# Cloud computing usage pattern. Can I have some port open within an app running in a cloud?

Tags: service, cloud, port

I'm developing a small web service which will partially rely on SMTP and FTP servers. I'm interested is it possible for me to create an app that will run within a cloud and still have some port open? I know I can forward request to a cloud after a request to port is made but is it possible to be handled by cloud from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends almost entirely on where your web service is hosted in the cloud.

Having said that, I would say in the majority of cases you can have ports opened, and thus make it a purely cloud hosted solution.

It all depends on your host provider and probably the type of hosting you're paying for.

Comment: Mmm. Could you please clarify - if I want such usecase to work I'll still have to pay both for cloud service and my hosting, right? (I think I was missing this point). Also - could you please recommend hosting provider that'll support purely cloud hosted application?

Comment: It depends which package you buy, I would imagine if you buy the right one, they'll come combined. Unfortunately I'd need much more information before recommending one... You might want to look at Rackspace, Amazon S3, or a local cloud provider.

Comment: I'll try to narrow the possibilities: I'm talking about .NET. Is it possible to do such a thing with MS Azure?

Comment: I've found GoGrid as a possible option. Thank you very much.